# Convert DateTime from strange format to DateTime object

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime

Normally converting `DateTime` from `string` is pretty easy, however I encountered this format :

```
Mon Jan 05 17:38:34 +1100 2015
```

which seems quite bizarre and also causes `DateTime.Parse()` to fail. All of the elements are there. Is there a way to convert this to DateTime without doing a `string.split(" ")` to divide it up into chunks. It does look like it could be an `ISO` standard although what standard is beyond me.

To clarify, I would like some assistance in converting the above sample `string` into a `DateTime` object in `.NET` using `C#`, and would prefer to do it without dividing the string if possible.

(@editors, why would you approve an edit changing a sentence with a pause into a run-on sentence that is bad english ? pls stop editing for the sake of epeen on edits -.- )

Comment: Check out [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [custom format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What do you believe the +1100 represents? Have you tried DateTime.TryParseExact?

Comment: @Blackwood The +1100 is the time zone offset.

Comment: +1100 is likely timezone offset. Whole string is clearly not ISO8601, but rather some random custom format.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - ^^  "some random custom format",   this was my thoughts/feelings on this as well.

Comment: @Blackwood - I didn't use TryParseExact until suggestions below.  Had a braindead moment ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the exact format:

```
var text = "Mon Jan 05 17:38:34 +1100 2015"
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As noted in comments, the lesser seen `zzz` part represents the [offset from UTC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#zzzSpecifier).  For this reason, you may prefer to parse with `DateTimeOffset` (using the same format string) as it handles this concept better than `DateTime`.  Your requirements may not allow this, however.

Comment: The problem is that `zzz` expects a colon in it.

Comment: You're right.  I guess it doesn't need the colon for parsing.

Comment: +1, actually this is a much better answer, which actually deals with the UTC offset, if `+1100` is that.

Comment: zzz ?  or zzzz ?    not sure what the difference is, but to me, it would seem need "zzzz" .   good solution as well.

Comment: Per the docs linked, `zzz` covers hours and minutes.  There is no `zzzz`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.  Will use zzz :)    Also, for the quick response ++epeen ^^

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var dt = "Mon Jan 05 17:38:34 +1100 2015";

DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,  out result);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: This answer is also really good to handle any potential exceptions or invalid formatting inline.

Comment: @SanuelJackson To actually handle an invalid format, it would be necessary to check whether TryParseExact returns True or False.

Comment: @Blackwood - correct, what I mean is this method will return DateTime object result. So if the the dev of the json api i am reading this from changes the format, it won't kill my program -- worst case, is no datetime for that field :)